# How to calculate MTD and QTD by YTD value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

There are some data in my table t1 looks like below:

```
date    dealer   YTD_Value    
2018-01   A       1100    
2018-02   A       2000
2018-03   A       3000
2018-04   A       4200
2018-05   A       5000
2018-06   A       5500
2017-01   B        100
2017-02   B        200
2017-03   B        500    
...      ...       ...
```

then I want to write a SQL to query this table and get below result:

```
date    dealer   YTD_Value    MTD_Value       QTD_Value
2018-01   A       1100           1100           1100
2018-02   A       2000            900           2000
2018-03   A       3000           1000           3000
2018-04   A       4200           1200           1200
2018-05   A       5000            800           2000
2018-06   A       5500            500           2500
2017-01   B        100            100            100
2017-02   B        200            100            200
2017-03   B        550            350            550    
...       ...      ...            ...            ...
```

`'YTD'` means Year to date
`'MTD'` means Month to date
`'QTD'` means Quarter to date

So if I want to calculate `MTD` and `QTD` value for dealer `'A'` in `'2018-01'`, it should be the same as `YTD`.

If I want to calculate `MTD` value for dealer `'A'` in `'2018-06'`, `MTD` value should equal to `YTD` value in `'2018-06'` minus `YTD` value in `'2018-05'`. And the QTD value in `'2018-06'` should equal to `YTD` value in `'2018-06'` minus `YTD` value in `'2018-03'` or equal to sum `MTD` value in (2018-04,2018-05,2018-06)

The same rule for other dealers such as B.

How can I write the SQL to achieve this purpose?

Comment: Check the `LAG` function

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Show us your query attempt and the issue you are facing which may need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QTD calculation is tricky, but you can do this query without subqueries.  The basic idea is to do a `lag()` for the monthly value.  Then use a `max()` analytic function to get the YTD value at the beginning of the quarter.

Of course, the first quarter of the year has no such value, so a `coalesce()` is needed.

Try this:

```
with t(dte, dealer, YTD_Value) as (  
      select '2018-01', 'A', 1100 from dual union all    
      select '2018-02', 'A', 2000 from dual union all
      select '2018-03', 'A', 3000 from dual union all
      select '2018-04', 'A', 4200 from dual union all
      select '2018-05', 'A', 5000 from dual union all
      select '2018-06', 'A', 5500 from dual union all
      select '2017-01', 'B', 100 from dual union all
      select '2017-02', 'B', 200 from dual union all
      select '2017-03', 'B', 550 from dual
   ) 
select t.*,
       (YTD_Value - lag(YTD_Value, 1, 0) over (partition by substr(dte, 1, 4) order by dte)) as MTD_Value,
       (YTD_Value -
        coalesce(max(case when substr(dte, -2) in ('03', '06', '09') then YTD_VALUE end) over
                                   (partition by substr(dte, 1, 4) order by dte rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                   ), 0
                )
       ) as QTD_Value
from t
order by 1
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=15013cf0cca390ba2e60e12facf62a47) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do the job. It uses a CTE that translates the varchar date column to dates, and then a few joins to recover the value to compare.

I tested it in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bda9a64529e979b8af03e760db460032) and the output matches your expected results.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE(my_date, 'YYYY-MM') my_date, dealer, ytd_value FROM my_table
)
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(ytd.my_date, 'YYYY-MM') my_date,
    ytd.ytd_value,
    ytd.dealer,
    ytd.ytd_value - NVL(mtd.ytd_value, 0) mtd_value,
    ytd.ytd_value - NVL(qtd.ytd_value, 0) qtd_value
FROM 
    cte ytd
    LEFT JOIN cte mtd ON mtd.my_date = ADD_MONTHS(ytd.my_date, -1) AND mtd.dealer = ytd.dealer
    LEFT JOIN cte qtd ON qtd.my_date = ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ytd.my_date, 'Q'), -1)  AND mtd.dealer = qtd.dealer
ORDER BY dealer, my_date
```

PS : `date` is a reserved word in most RDBMS (including Oracle), I renamed that column to `my_date` in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()` windows analytic and `sum() over ..` aggregation functions as :

```
select "date",dealer,YTD_Value,MTD_Value,
       sum(MTD_Value) over (partition by qt order by "date")
          as QTD_Value 
  from
  (
   with t("date",dealer,YTD_Value) as
   (  
    select '2018-01','A',1100 from dual union all    
    select '2018-02','A',2000 from dual union all
    select '2018-03','A',3000 from dual union all
    select '2018-04','A',4200 from dual union all
    select '2018-05','A',5000 from dual union all
    select '2018-06','A',5500 from dual union all
    select '2017-01','B', 100 from dual union all
    select '2017-02','B', 200 from dual union all
    select '2017-03','B', 550 from dual
   ) 
   select t.*,
          t.YTD_Value - nvl(lag(t.YTD_Value) 
          over (partition by substr("date",1,4) order by substr("date",1,4) desc, "date"),0) 
             as MTD_Value,
          substr("date",1,4)||to_char(to_date("date",'YYYY-MM'),'Q')
             as qt,
          substr("date",1,4) as year
        from t
      order by year desc, "date"
   )     
  order by year desc, "date";
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/FUY4785)</kbd>